# How many emails or SingleEmailMessages can be sent as part of a single sendEmail method invocation?

Tags: singleemailmessage

I see the governor limits for maximum no. of sendEmail invocations per transaction as 10 in this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section

But it does not say how many emails I can send per sendEmail invocation.

Comment: You can send as many in a single list as you can fit into other governor limits (heap, SOQL, CPU, daily email sends, if not sending to users). There doesn't appear to be any explicit upper limit, just whichever governor limit you'd trip over first.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox This is exactly what i was looking for!